JSON schema additionalProperties=false with $ref - allowing additional properties
can someone please help me to fix my schema in a way that other than defined properties will be rejected.
Thanks for any suggestion!
My schema:
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "description": "Comment describing your JSON Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "msg": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/msg"
        }
    },
    "$defs": {
        "msg": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "number": {
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "street_name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "street_type": {
                    "enum": [
                        "Street",
                        "Avenue",
                        "Boulevard"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "street_type"
            ]
        }
    }
}
  

My json:
{
    "number": 1600,
    "street_name": "Pennsylvania",
    "street_type": "Avenue",
    "direction": "NW"
}

My expectation with the sample data below is that during the schema validation "direction" will be rejected as not defined in schema but it is not (I'm trying to use some online validation tool, as well as my Altova XMLSpy).
